# Prevent multiple request inside ng for

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have img with src binded to api call.

```
<img [src]="getSiteImage(site.id)" />
```

In my component i have:

```
  public getSiteImage(id:number) {
    this.sitesClient.getSiteImage(5).subscribe((res: any) => {
      return res.image
    })
  }
```

When components render getSiteImage() is called multiple times with the same id value, so there are a lot of unneccessary calls ( is inside ngFor, so I think its internal Angular behavior to execute this ngfor few times when components render). Is there any way to call this request only once for specyfic id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exactly is the reason why it isn't a good idea to bind a function to a directive. In case of default change detection strategy (similar to yours), the function will be triggered in each change detection cycle.

### Solution 1: local variable

Trigger the request in `ngOnInit`, store the response in a variable and bind it. `forkJoin` with `Array#map` is used to trigger multiple requests in parallel. Then RxJS `map` operator is used to append the value to the existing object.

**Controller**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  forkJoin(
    this.sites.map(site => this.sitesClient.getSiteImage(site.id).pipe(
      map((res: any) => ({...site, 'imageSrc': res.image))
    )
  ).subscribe((sites: any) => {
    this.sites = sites;
  });
}
```

**Template**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let site of sites">
  ...
  <img [src]="site.imageSrc" />
</ng-container>
```

### Solution 2: `async` pipe

Instead of the subscription in the controller, if the value isn't required there you could use the `async` pipe in the template to trigger the request.

**Controller**

```js
sites$: Obseravble<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.sites$ = forkJoin(
    this.sites.map(site => this.sitesClient.getSiteImage(site.id).pipe(
      map((res: any) => ({...site, 'imageSrc': res.image))
    )
  );
}
```

**Template**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(sites$ | async) as sitesRes">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let site of sitesRes">
    ...
    <img [src]="site.imageSrc" />
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```